Should an AWS Lambda function written in Javascript/Typescript t return a value when not responding to an HTTP request?
I have been struggling to find a good answer to whether or not AWS Lambda functions written in Javascript/Typescript should return a value when they aren't serving up an HTTP request response or returning a value that another function will consume? The documentation here does not say anything but I have seen online that you can even return a Response types object anyway:
{ statusCode: 200, message: "Processed successfully." }

The Handler type associated with aws-lambda looks like this:
export type Handler<TEvent = any, TResult = any> = (
    event: TEvent,
    context: Context,
    callback: Callback<TResult>,
) => void | Promise<TResult>;


It also says in the notes for the type that "if you implement your handler as an async function, you will automatically return a promise that will resolve with a returned value, or reject with a thrown value."
I'm hoping to settle this more clearly with this question. Here are my questions:

Is there any actual value to returning a value when there's no direct use for the value (e.g. request response or a value being consumed by a calling function)?
Does the AWS Lambda system or AWS Log system someone do something with any return value in such a scenario?

